# PHP - Can a foreach be used on an array that contains strings?

Tags: php, string, foreach

I have an array of strings and I am trying to implement a foreach to echo each of the strings like the following:

```
$options = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5');


foreach ($options as $option)
{
    echo $option;
}
```

I've also tried

```
 foreach (options as $key => $option)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: YES - foreach can be used on any array regardless of it's contents.

Comment: So what results did you actually get when you tried the code you've posted here? just curious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can - see other answers. I just want to add this consideration:

```
$options = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5');

foreach ($options as $option) // Prints 'string1', 'string2' and so on
{
    echo $option;
}
```

If you also need the index (variabile `$i` will be "binded" to the index, starting from zero):

```
foreach ($options as $i => $option) // Prints '0', '1' and so on (as numbers)
{
    echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `$`:

```
foreach ($options as $option)
{
    echo $option;
}
```

Comment: sorry, that was an error with the question because obviously these aren't the exact variable names.

Comment: ...then your code is correct and works (just tested it to be shure)! Which means the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: yes, got it eventually, my code was mixed up inside the while loop for a mysql query so that was the problem, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes you can very well use it.

```
<?php

$options = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 

'string5');


foreach ($options as $valueinoptions)
{
    echo $valueinoptions;
    echo "<br>";
}  

?>
```